# "Recycler View..No adapter attached: skipping layout" error using Async Task in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

```
public class ReferralStatus extends Fragment {

public MyPendingAdapter pAdapter;
public RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_referral_status, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.pendingRecyclerList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    PendingAsyncTask pendingRunner = new PendingAsyncTask();
    pendingRunner.execute("someURL");
}

public class MyPendingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyPendingAdapter.PendingUserHolder> {

    Context context;
    String[] pendingUserArray, socialSitesArray;


    public MyPendingAdapter(Context c, String[] pendingUserList, String[] socialSites) {

        Log.d("golu", "pendingConstructor");
        this.context=c;
        this.pendingUserArray=pendingUserList;
        this.socialSitesArray=socialSites;
    }

    public class PendingUserHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView pendingUsername;
        TextView socialSite;

        public PendingUserHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            pendingUsername = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pendingUsername);
            socialSite= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.socialSiteLabel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PendingUserHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Log.d("golu", "pendingHolder");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_list_row,parent,false);
        PendingUserHolder holder = new PendingUserHolder(row);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PendingUserHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.pendingUsername.setText(pendingUserArray[position]);
        holder.socialSite.setText(socialSitesArray[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("golu", "pendingCount");
        return pendingUserArray.length;
    }
}

public class PendingAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>{

    String [] pendingUserList, socialSitesMedium;



    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        //just returning simple boolean value
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        if(aBoolean)
        {
             //Hardcoding Arrays for now                      
             pendingUserList=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pendingUserList);
                         socialSitesMedium=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.socialSites);



             pAdapter = new MyPendingAdapter(getActivity(),pendingUserList,socialSitesMedium);
             recyclerView.setAdapter(pAdapter);


        }
    }
}
```

//Here is the XML file

```
<LinearLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pending"
            android:id="@+id/pendingLabel"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/pendingRecyclerList"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

//Its showing the Skipping layout error ....What am I doing wrong?
//FYI: I tried initialising RecyclerView and setting the LinearLayoutManager in onPostExecute....it still didnt work :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in OnCreateView method 
You need to initialise the adapter there and set the adapter to the recycler view.
As the adapter will pass no data you can update the display later.
As the onCreateView  Method is the method which updates the display,so its important to initialise it else it will give an  error "no adapter attached skipping display"

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

RecyclerView (and also ListView) requires Adapter to be able to work, because adapter is the way these widgets gets the data to display from. You have adapter  in your code but you lack the code that tells RecyclerView to use it: [setAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)).

See https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html for more details

Comment: I did set the adapter in onPostExecute na?

Comment: @user2508635 do it in `onCreateView`. You can refresh your adapter in `onPostExecute` after updating the data that populates your recyclerview in onPostExecute